# CSS Background Position Custom X and Y Degree

Tags: html, css

I have PSD image that need customization for background position degree between x and y. this is my PSD
[image]

this is some of my code in css

```
html{
background:#aea99f;
}
body{
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/H3fh4Ht.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: 48% 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 94%;
}
```

But how the logic to customize the slope at the top, side right-left and bottom?

JS Example http://jsfiddle.net/zmkkdj46/

Thanks

Comment: pls send live link or, JSFiddle demo for more understanding.

Comment: updated js here http://jsfiddle.net/zmkkdj46/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Jagdish answer , in order to work in firefox please add this

**HTML**

```
    <div id="div1">
  123 rtrrrrr rt

</div>
<svg id="svg1">
    <defs>
        <clippath id="my-definition" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points=".09 1, 0.94 1, 1 0, 0 0"></polygon>
        </clippath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 94%;
    height:100%;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(9% 100%, 94% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
clip-path: url(#my-definition)
}
svg{
  width: 1%;
    height:100%;
}
html, body {width:100%; height: 100%; background:#aea99f;}
body{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```

Updated Fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/zx8njaga/) :

By adding the `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` will do the trick

Comment: @Alan El-nino Malmsteen please refer this solution and try it in firefox

Answer (score 1):

See Example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcr2we5r/)

HTML:

```
<div>
 123
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
 width: 94%;
 height:100%;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(9% 100%, 94% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
 clip-path: polygon(9% 100%, 94% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
}

html, body {width:100%; height: 100%; background:#aea99f;}
body{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```

Comment: It works in chrome, but not work in firefox, thanks for help